# Vb.net Visual Studio 2022 keyword 'address' not found

Tags: mysql, vb.net, visual-studio-2022, keyword

Can please someone guide me where can I identify this address the error is talking to. Whenever I run the project, after connecting the database. This error shows up:

[image]

```
Private Sub Main_Menu_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        conn = New MySqlConnection
        conn.ConnectionString = "server=(LocalDb)\cedriclocaldb;username=cedricoruga;password=123456;database=consignmentdatabase"

        Try
            conn.Open()
            sql = "select * from consignment_tbl_ced"
            command.Connection = conn
            command.CommandText = sql
            myadapter.SelectCommand = command
            myadapter.Fill(mydata)
            DataGridView1.DataSource = mydata
            conn.Close()
            MessageBox.Show("Connection to database is successful!", "Testing Connection to MySQL Database")
            conn.Close()
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox("Error:" & Err.Description)
        Finally

            conn.Dispose()

        End Try
    End Sub
```

Comment: [ConnectionStrings.com](https://www.connectionstrings.com/mysql/) is using `Uid` and `Pwd` (instead of "username" and "password") and doesn't use "Address" either. What package are you using for the MySqlConnection?

Comment: On which line is the error occurring? It would be helpful to know. Unrelated, but you're closing `conn` twice, so the second one must fail. It would be better in any case to use `Using conn As MySqlConnection = New MySqlConnection` so you don't have to worry about such things.

Comment: LocalDB is a SQL Server thing, not MySQL. I think you need to spend some time to understand what database you're actually using.

Comment: @HansKeﬆing, i use NuGet Package.

Comment: @MichaelFoster, That is where it come really hard, it doesnt show any line where the error occurs. only error box pops and says " keyword 'address' not found.

Comment: So if it isn't a thrown exception then you can add a breakpoint at the beginning and step through the code. Pay attention to which line you're about to run, since it won't stop automatically.

Comment: The exception will tell you what line it was thrown on if you care to look at it in your `Catch` block. Alternatively, comment out the `Catch` block and then the debugger will break on the offending line. Or you can configure VS to break whenever that specific exception type is thrown rather then when it goes uncaught.

Comment: To be clear, are you really trying to connect to a MySQL database or is it a SQL Server database? If it's using the LocalDB feature that was installed with VS then that's SQL Server.

Comment: "NuGet" is where you *get* packages. The important part is *which* package. And whether it applies to the database you are trying to connect to.